# How to view image field from DRF in a Vue Template

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I try to learn `DRF` as `api` and `VueJs` as `frontend`. I have created a `serializer` class for my `Article` model :

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    image = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        exclude = [  "updated_at"]

    def get_image(self, instance):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        image_url = instance.image.url
        return request.build_absolute_uri(image_url)
```

and a viewset:

```
class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by("-created_at")
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = "slug"

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

now I try to view my image in a vue template:

```
<div class="ui-block">
    <!-- Post -->
    <article class="hentry blog-post">
        <div class="post-thumb">
            <router-link :to="{ name: 'article', params: { slug: article.slug }}"
              class="h5 post-title">
                  <img src="article.get_image()" alt=""> 
            </router-link>
        </div>
        <div class="post-content">
           {{ article.content }}
        </div> 
     </article>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to get the `image` in a template by `ModelSerializer`?

Thanks

Ps: missing part about question was the url.py I have used to redirect all requests to LoginMixin

```
re_path(r"^.*$", IndexTemplateView.as_view(), name="entry-point"),
```

This line causes problems.

Comment: The `get_image` should be on the `model` and not the `serializer`

Comment: And you can use `article.image.url` too

Comment: this is vue template, not a django template. I can view the answer in the console. but i cannot see the image.